# Predict/infer asynchronously with a Keras or TF model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I've been trying to use queues and threading to run predictions on a keras model asynchronously while I compile inputs and then retrieve outputs on the fly.

To do this I'm trying to use `model.predict()` on a generator that pulls inputs from a queue, and then use a custom on_predict_batch_end callback to push results to another queue as soon as they are computed.

My method runs, but unfortunately I can't seem to be able to retrieve the predictions from within the callback. I can only get a non-eager Tensor that doesn't give me access to the actual outputs. `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` doesn't help.

Here is a quick summary of what I am trying to do:

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread


# i/o queues
input_queue = Queue(1)
output_queue = Queue(1)

# inputs generator:
def feed():
    while True:
        yield input_queue.get()

# Custom Keras callback that is supposed to pull predictions on the fly
# and add them to output queue:
class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_predict_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        # Retrieve "output" put in output queue:
        output_queue.put(self.model.layers[-1].output)

# Prediction function to use in thread call:
def prediction_function():
    model.predict(feed(),verbose=1, callbacks=[CustomCallback()])

# Start prediction thread:
pt = Thread(target=prediction_function, daemon=True)
pt.start()

# Add input to the queue and retrieve when output is ready:
for i in input_data:
    iq.put(i)
    output_data += [oq.get()]
```

This runs fine, but again all I get in my output_data list is a non-eager tensor. Because it is non-eager `.numpy()` doesn't work and `.eval()` would defeat the purpose. Is there a way to access predictions on the fly without calling again model.predict() for every new input in the queue which is very slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem. If you look in keras's predict method, it passes the batch outputs to on_predict_batch_end() through the logs. All you need to do in the callback is forward it to the queue:

```py
class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_predict_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        # Retrieve "output" put in output queue:
        output_queue.put(logs['outputs'])
```